# Kendo Grid server wrappers not sending sort request as JSON

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I downloaded a Telerik [grid-crud](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net-mvc/tree/master/grid-crud) sample form their public samples on GitHub

i converted it from client side javascript initialization to server side wrappers (downloaded the trial)

here`s the code (typed in by hand here, the dev machine is not connected to the inet)

```razor
@(Html.Kendo.Grid<SampleViewModel>()
    .Name("SamplGrid")
    .Columns( c=>
    {
        c.Bound(s => s.id);
        c.Bound(s => s.Name);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .DataSource( ds => ds
     .Ajax()
     .PageSize(10)
     .Read( r => r.Action("Read", "Samples").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
     )
)
```

**the problem is** the sort does not work.

the sort expression sent to the server in my version looks like:
`take=10&skip=0&page=1&pagesize=10&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5d=id%5Bdir%5d=asc`

where in the original sample it looks like:

`{"take":10,"skip":0,"page":1,"pagesize":10,"sort":[{"field":"id","dir":"asc","compare":null}]}`

in other words the sample sends JSON but my code generates something else.

how to get the grid to send the same JSON using server wrappers?

Comment: I could not undrstand your question. But this is not required here .Type(HttpVerbs.Post)

Comment: @Iman , edited the question, can you have a look ?

Comment: @HaBo i removed the `HttpVerbs.Post` but MVC does not allow `Get` by default so i got a `404 Not found`. i don`t want to use `Get` since it has the length limitation.

Comment: `take=10&skip=0&page=1&pagesize=10&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5d=id%5Bdir%5d=asc` is encoded which equals to `take=10&skip=0&page=1&pagesize=10&sort[0][field]=id[dir]=asc`. it is not important how data for sorting is send, if your problem is sorting columns not work, it means you forgot something in your code. By the way I can't understand your problem very well. is it your grid's sort not work? also check this sample too: [Grid / Sorting](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/sorting.html) section :(`ASP.NET MVC / sorting.cshtml`)

Comment: thanks @Iman, you pointed me in the right direction. it actually IS important if you send JSON or not as far as the server is concerned.  see my answer below

Comment: @Menahem You are welcome, and I'm glad that your problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK , i have found the problem, and the solution.

As @Iman said the data sent to the server is encoded rather than just JSON,
and the server was expecting JSON.

sort was not working, as the sort expression was invalid as far as the server was concerned.

To make the grid send JSON it needs to be configured to do so. The problem is the server wrappers don't support this specific feature. The only way to do this is to configure this in the client side using javascript.

i found [this](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/grid/changing-the-contenttype-in-the-http-request.aspx) post in Telerik's support forums to be very helpful.